# Beam SQL Not Firing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, spotify-scio, beam-sql

I am building a simple prototype wherein I am reading data from Pubsub and using BeamSQL, code snippet as below

```
    val eventStream: SCollection[String] = sc.pubsubSubscription[String]("projects/jayadeep-etl-platform/subscriptions/orders-dataflow")
      .withFixedWindows(Duration.standardSeconds(10))

    val events: SCollection[DemoEvents] = eventStream.applyTransform(ParDo.of(new DoFnExample()))

    events.map(row=>println("Input Stream:" + row))

    val pickup_events = SideOutput[DemoEvents]()
    val delivery_events = SideOutput[DemoEvents]()

    val (mainOutput: SCollection[DemoEvents], sideOutputs: SideOutputCollections)= events
      .withSideOutputs(pickup_events, delivery_events)
      .flatMap {
        case (evts, ctx) =>
          evts.eventType match {
            // Send to side outputs via `SideOutputContext`
            case "pickup" => ctx.output(pickup_events,evts)
            case "delivery" => ctx.output(delivery_events,evts)
          }
          Some(evts)
      }

    val pickup: SCollection[DemoEvents] = sideOutputs(pickup_events)
    val dropoff = sideOutputs(delivery_events)

    pickup.map(row=>println("Pickup:" + row))
    dropoff.map(row=>println("Delivery:" + row))


    val consolidated_view = tsql"select $pickup.order_id as orderId, $pickup.area as pickup_location, $dropoff.area as dropoff_location , $pickup.restaurant_id as resturantId from $pickup as pickup left outer join $dropoff as dropoff ON $pickup.order_id = $dropoff.order_id ".as[Output]


    consolidated_view.map(row => println("Output:" + row))

    sc.run().waitUntilFinish()

    ()
```

I am using Directrunner for testing it locally and I am able to see the results right until the beam sql is executed. The output from beam sql is not getting printed.

```
Input Stream:DemoEvents(false,pickup,Bangalore,Indiranagar,1566382242,49457442008,1566382242489,7106576,1566382242000,178258,7406545542,,false,null,htr23e22-329a-4b05-99c1-606a3ccf6a48,972)
Pickup:DemoEvents(false,pickup,Bangalore,Indiranagar,1566382242,49457442008,1566382242489,7106576,1566382242000,178258,7406545542,,false,null,htr23e22-329a-4b05-99c1-606a3ccf6a48,972)
Input Stream:DemoEvents(false,delivery,Bangalore,Indiranagar,1566382242,49457442008,2566382242489,7106576,1566382242000,178258,7406545542,,false,null,htr23e22-329a-4b05-99c1-606a3ccf6a48,972)
Delivery:DemoEvents(false,delivery,Bangalore,Indiranagar,1566382242,49457442008,2566382242489,7106576,1566382242000,178258,7406545542,,false,null,htr23e22-329a-4b05-99c1-606a3ccf6a48,972)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to a bug in DirectRunner, when I changed the runner to DataflowRunner the code ran as exepected.